# Modifying code to default to option instead of asking user for selection?

Tags: python

I am not very experienced with python, just trying to make a modification to the code of a program I purchased.

The code runs in the command terminal and its function is to gather data. It gives you the option of gathering the data in either csv or json. It prompts you once with asking which format and a second time for confirmation.

```
Please enter output format (csv/json)  
Do you want to extract data in {} format? (y/n)
```

I am trying to change this to just do csv by default, and not be prompted for either choosing or confirming

I believe the relevant code from the program is the following ( this isn't all consecutive ). How do I alter the first part to just be 'csv' and do I need to do anything beyond deleting the entire def getConfirmMessage block to wipe that from the code?

```
if spiderToExecute in range(1, 7):
    while True:
        outputFormat    = click.prompt('Please enter output format (csv/json)', default='csv')
        outputFormat    = ''.join(outputFormat).lower()
        if outputFormat in ['json', 'csv']:
            break


settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', outputFormat)
settings.set('FEED_URI', './data/{}.{}'.format(spiderConf['log_output_name_format'], outputFormat))
settings.set('LOG_FILE', './log/{}.log'.format(spiderConf['log_output_name_format']))



def getConfirmMessage(spiderToExecute, outputFormat):
confirmMessages = {
    1: 'Do you want to extract data from in {} format ?'.format(outputFormat),
    2: 'Do you want to extract data from in {} format ?'.format(outputFormat),
}

return confirmMessages[spiderToExecute]
```

edit: more code

```
    if not click.confirm(getConfirmMessage(spiderToExecute, outputFormat), default=True):
        click.echo()
        click.secho(' Please relaunch the command to select new options! ', bg='red')
        click.echo()
        raise click.Abort()
```

Comment: You should also post the code that calls the `getConfirmMessage` function.

Comment: Could you just replace the while true loop with `outputFormat = "csv"` as a first step? That shouldn't ask anymore. We need more code no see how to remove the confirming functionality.

Comment: @DROPTABLEnames  first part worked, thanks, super simple, my bad, as far as the 2nd part i just added more code to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete steps (maybe):

Remove the while loop and replace with `outputFormat = "csv"`.

You should be able to completely remove the code block you posted (`if not click.confirm...`). If that doesn't work, you'll need to post the code for `click.confirm`.